# Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 1025

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

I am going through this tutorial (link:https://www.murdo.ch/blog/build-a-contact-form-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1) to create a simple contact us form on my existing rails application. After completing the tutorial and testing on my development environment I notice that my smtp settings are interferring with my contact us form. Basically I just want send a message to an email address so I dont need the sender mail address for this. I tried removing the SMTP settings in my development.rb file but then I get this error when clicking the submit button:

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED in MessagesController#create
>   Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 1025

I tried solving in different ways but I come back to this same error. Here's my code:

```
model/message.rb:
class Message 
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :body
  validates :name, :email, :body, presence: true
end
```

Here's my message controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @message = Message.new
 end
 def create

  @message = Message.new message_params

  if @message.valid?
    MessageMailer.contact_me(@message).deliver_now
    redirect_to new_message_url, notice: "Message received"
  else
  render :new
 end
end

 def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :body)
 end
end
```

My view:new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @message, url: create_message_url do |f| %>
 <%= notice %>
 <%= @message.errors.full_messages.join(', ') %>

 <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'name' %>
 <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'email' %>
 <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: 'body' %>
 <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```

My Mailer:

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer
 def contact_me(message)
  @greeting = 'Hi'
  @body = message.body

  mail to: "notifications@example.com", from: message.email
 end
end
```

And my Development.rb/SMTP settings code:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => 'localhost',
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'localhost:3000',
  :user_name            => 'example@gmail.com',
  :password             => '######',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  
 }
```

I just want to get rid of the smtp settings but unfortunately I cannot, is there any way to override these settings or an alternate solution or am I missing something,
Any help will be appreciated, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [Mailcatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) to catch any email you send from your development environnement (there's a part for rails configuration in the documentation)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, its helpful but it after every email send the connection would close, not sure why.